# How to change the default terminal in dolphin?

Tags: lubuntu, dolphin, lxterminal

OS: Lubuntu 18.04 x64

I installed Dolphin file explorer and it works just fine. Only the terminal wouldn't open!

When I try: Tools -> Open terminal, nothing happens!

Also when I try to activate the terminal panel, the terminal wouldn't work.

I think the reason for this is dolphin's default terminal command is not executing the default terminal on lxde which is lxterminal...

Is there any way to make it work on Lubuntu? (make it work with lxterminal without having to install another terminal program)

Comment: According to [[SOLVED] Change Dolphin FM's default terminal](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1621231#p1621231), the terminal used by `Dolphin` depends on what is present in `~/.config/kdeglobals`. Is such a file present in your Lubuntu as a result on installing Dolphin on your system? If it is, follow the instructions in the link. Maybe things will work :)

Comment: @DKBose Thanks for replying :) It worked with launching the terminal, but still the terminal panel is not working :( .

Comment: Thanks @DKBose it worked. I just had to change `qterminal` with `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 6):

Open the following file:

```
nano ~/.config/kdeglobals
```

And add this at the end of the file:

```
[General]
TerminalApplication=gnome-terminal
```

Comment: You have to restart Dolphin after that

Answer (score 1):

To change it from a GUI, go to System Settings -> Applications -> Default Applications